# What is the meaning of 未体?

Tags: translation

Here is an example that came from a document talking about salary bonuses: 未体年假折现.

My best guess for 未体 would be "haven't done". So the example above would be translated to "discount for not taking annual leave".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's a typo, it should be 未休， which not yet taken
未休年假折现： cash redeems for un-taken annual holiday

Comment: 未 means 'not yet', 休 is 'taking a holiday'.  我的年假还未休。我还未休年假。

Answer (score 2):

"未体" it's a typo, 100% for sure.

the correct word based on the context should be "未休", means not taken.

the reason why this typo happened could possibly be that the typer was using a kind of Chines input method based on characters strokes, rather than IMEs based on pronunciations, because "体" and "休" are quite similar in strokes.

Comment: It may come from a scan, which caused the typo.

Comment: yes, OCR technology also makes mistakes sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

That's right, it's a typo, it should be `未休`, `休假` means `take holidays`, `未` means `haven't done something`.

so

> 未休年假折现 means  compensate someone by money if he does not take annual
>   leave.